# Where can maaser sheini be eaten? (Size of Jerusalem)

Tags: geography, maaser-tithes, yerushalayim-jerusalem

Maaser sheini must be eaten in Jerusalem. For this purpose, [halachic Jerusalem is the same size](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/52450/5151) as when it was set by the Sanhedrin ~2000 years ago.

On today's map, what is included? (An image with a border would be very helpful).

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hasmonean_Baris#/media/File:Jerusalem_before_Herod_circa_37BC.svg

Comment: As an aside, the borders of Yerushalayim, at least at the time of the Sanhedrin, could easily change. Check out the second perek of Shavuos.